# Click event on span element works on desktop, but not mobile (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, responsive

Click event on span element fires on desktop but not on mobile. The span is the temperature unit that is next to current temperature which populates once the user has clicked the "get weather" button.

This is the section of code that is related to the span click event:

```
$(document).on('click', "span" , function(){
    var str=document.getElementById("tempUnits").innerHTML;
    if (str==="Celsius"){
      document.getElementById("tempUnits").innerHTML="Fahrenheit";
      $("#temp").html(tempC + '<span id="tempUnitsSpan"><strong> C </strong></span>' + " and " + weatherDescription);
    }

    else if (str==="Fahrenheit"){
      document.getElementById("tempUnits").innerHTML="Celsius";
          tempF=Math.max( Math.round((tempC*1.8+32) * 10) / 10, 2.8 ).toFixed(2);
        console.log(tempF);

      $("#temp").html(tempF + '<span id="tempUnitsSpan"><strong> F  </strong></span>' + " and " + weatherDescription);
    }
```

[page](https://codepen.io/gm-gis/full/eyKadO/)

[page w/ code](https://codepen.io/gm-gis/pen/eyKadO?editors=1111)

Comment: does it work on mobile when you click twice?

Comment: @messerbill (no it did not work after clicking twice with original code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing it works if the element is tapped twice on mobile. To get around this, add a touchstart event. The touchstart event is fired when a touch point is placed on the touch surface.

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', "span" , function(){
}
```